# Microsoft Open SDK 2.0 to generate excel file using c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

Please refer link for the code i am using to generate excel file from data table. I am able to generate excel file successfully.

But the problem/Challenge/Question is as follows.

1. I Want to generate column as per the datatype so if Column value contains date the it cell format should be date(dd/mm/yyy) if number then numeric. ans so on...
2. I have tried to generate excel file as per data format you can see specific methods to generate cell value. But the problem is when user download the file it will gives the warning message that "Excel found unreadable content 'filename'. Do you want to recover the content of this workbook?". I don,t want that warning message should come.
3. If I am writing everything as text without format then file will open without any warning message and after downloading file, if user tries to format respective column in date or number format then also it will not allow user to format/slice & dice data in excel file.

Reference :- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/263106/Export-Tabular-Data-in-CSV-and-Excel-Formats-Throu

Please let me know the solution if anybody has.

I am using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`

```
        private Cell CreateTextCell(string header, UInt32 index, string text)
        {
            var cell = new Cell {DataType = CellValues.InlineString, CellReference = header + index};
            var istring = new InlineString();
            var t = new Text {Text = text};
            istring.Append(t);
            cell.Append(istring);

            return cell;
        }

        private Cell CreateDateCell(string header, UInt32 index, DateTime sDate)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell();

            cell.DataType = CellValues.Date;
            cell.CellReference = header + index;
            cell.StyleIndex = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(14);
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue { Text = sDate.ToOADate().ToString() };
            return cell;
        }


        private Cell CreateNumberCell(string header, UInt32 index, string text)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell();

            cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
            cell.CellReference = header + index;

            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);

            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: As a suggestion: Use something like EPPLUS. It does a very good job to hide the low level plumbing of Open XMl SDK.
I've worked with both and cannot say how I love EPPLUS ;)

Comment: Yes it is, even the license is very good for developers.

Comment: If anybody knows solution using Open XML SDK then it will help me lot...

Answer (score 0):

I have moved to EPPlus .net library to generate excel file and it is very easy to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have the complete solution but you can try the below steps to find the root cause:

1. One of the reasons for unreadable content error (There are many reasons for this but considering that you are just writing from the datatable only).is if there is a mismatch between the StyleIndex/Datatype/Cellvalue format
2. To identify the root cause you can try:
   Create a sample excel and directly write a cell (only a cell) with number, it that goes on fine, try the next datatype one by one.
   Next try to write them one after the other.
   Do this and sort down the types which are causing problems.

Next try to vary the StyleIndex/cellFormat with that type (you can check for examples online) till the format is fine without error. Once you are good with all types, you can try writing to the entire excel. 
You can also use this method if you want to try something new using OpenXML (since you do not have well documented examples for everything Online)

Another way to identify issues is to use Openxml productivity tool and do a validation of the file.